How to add a list webpart in a classic page using PowerShell
I have a classic page in SharePoint Online. It's a standard homepage from a teamsite in a classic web and I want to add a list webpart to it.
When the web is created, the Home.aspx has three webparts, a Promoted Links webpart ("Get started with your site"), a Documents webpart and a Newsfeed webpart. This is all standard.
I need to remove the Promoted Links webpart and the Documents and run this:
# Remove the Promoted Links webpart:
$wpId = (Get-PnPWebPart -ServerRelativePageUrl "$relLeafURL/SitePages/Home.aspx" -Connection $conn | Where-Object {$_.Webpart.Title -eq "Get started with your site" }).Id
Remove-PnPWebPart -ServerRelativePageUrl "$relLeafURL/SitePages/Home.aspx" -Identity $wpId -Connection $conn

# Remove the Documents webpart:
$wpId = (Get-PnPWebPart -ServerRelativePageUrl "$relLeafURL/SitePages/Home.aspx" -Connection $conn | Where-Object {$_.Webpart.Title -eq "Documents"}).Id
Remove-PnPWebPart -ServerRelativePageUrl "$relLeafURL/SitePages/Home.aspx" -Identity $wpId -Connection $conn

The two webparts are gone from Home.aspx, only the Newsfeed remains. Excellent.
Now I need to add a custom list webpart called Contacts. I get the XML from the AllItems view and add it to the page:
# Add webpart Contacts:
$webPartXml = Get-PnPWebPartXml -Identity Contacts -ServerRelativePageUrl "$relLeafURL/Lists/Contacts/AllItems.aspx" -Connection $conn
Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage -ServerRelativePageUrl "$relLeafURL/SitePages/Home.aspx" -XML $webPartXml -ZoneId "WPZ" -ZoneIndex 2 -Connection $conn

The webpart is indeed added to the page, but when I edit the page it's not there. Only the Newsfeed webpart which was created by default shows up. This means that I can't change any settings for the webpart, since it doesn't show in edit mode.
The webpart is listed if I run Get-PnPWebPart and also shows when I add ?contents=1 to the URL. Just not when I edit the page.
I think for some reason my webpart doesn't end up in a webpart zone, but I can't figure out how to do this. Can anyone please help?


Try adding the list web part this way.
1.Create the Web Part XML:

Use the following template for a .dwp file:
<webParts> <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2"> <metaData> <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" /> <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage> </metaData> <data> <properties> <property name="ListName" type="string">{list-guid}</property> <property name="Title" type="string">Your List Title</property> </properties> </data> </webPart> </webParts>

Replace {list-guid} with the actual GUID of your list. You can get
the GUID by navigating to the list settings and copying it from the
URL.


2.Save the XML as a .dwp File:

Save the above XML content to a file with a .dwp extension, for example, C:\path\to\your\webpart.dwp.

3.Add the Web Part to the Page:

Use the Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage cmdlet to add the web part to your page:
$page = "YourPage.aspx" $dwpPath = "C:\\path\\to\\your\\webpart.dwp" Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage -ServerRelativePageUrl "/sites/yoursite/SitePages/$page" -Path $dwpPath -ZoneId "Main" -ZoneIndex 1


